# Drupal-7 - how to hv AJAX form function in "basic page" content

Tags: ajax, drupal-7

i want to ask if i want to add jquery AJAX form function in a Drupal "Page" content, where should i add the javascript code (just typed in the "page" body)? and where would be the form target (the backend process script) ??

or i need to write a module instead of using "page" content?

thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply add jquery inside page by using following function which is responsible for including jquery file inside your page

```
<?php 
drupal_add_js('--your jQuery code--','inline');
?>
```

you can also include the js file by

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'module-name') .'/myjquery.js');
```

remember! use 'jQuery' instaed of $ sign inside jQ code.

Comment: but where should i put the <?php xxxxx?> those php code?
"page" <-- do u mean the Drupal original basic page content? 
cox there is only  "title" and "content" part, how to write the php code?

Comment: yes you can put it inside 'content' or 'body' but change the text format to 'php code'. For this you have to enable a drupal core module 'php filter' first.